# Indy UDP Read Contents of Adata

Tags: delphi, udp, indy

I am using Indy UDP Server to read a string of data. However, I do not really know how to work with the `Adata` parameter. I can get around it by converting it to binary by using the `ByteToBin` function below and then convert it to hex by using `BintoHex1`.  But I really feel this is really stupid and it works really slow.  Does anyone know how I can directly get the results without those two conversions?

Thanks!!

Here are the codes:

```
procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  Buf: TIdBytes;
  buffer: string;
  Data_received: string;
begin
  if bytestostring(AData) <> 'Hello' then
  begin
    buffer := HextoString('00');
    SetLength(Buf, Length(buffer));
    CopyTIdString(buffer, Buf, 0);
    ABinding.SendTo(ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, Buf);

  Data_received := BinToHex1(ByteToBin(AData[1]) + ByteToBin(AData[2]) +
    ByteToBin(AData[3]) + ByteToBin(AData[4]) + ByteToBin(AData[5]) +
    ByteToBin(AData[6]) + ByteToBin(AData[7]) + ByteToBin(AData[8]) +
    ByteToBin(AData[9]) + ByteToBin(AData[10]) + ByteToBin(AData[11]) +
    ByteToBin(AData[12]));

  end;
  memo1.Lines.Add(Data_received);
  Memo1.GoToTextEnd;
end;

function TForm1.ByteToBin(aByte: byte): String;
Const
  c10: Array [Boolean] of Char = ('0', '1');
Var
  eLoop1: byte;
Begin
  SetLength(Result, 8);
  For eLoop1 := 7 downto 0 do
    Result[8 - eLoop1] := c10[(aByte and (1 shl eLoop1)) <> 0];
End;

function TForm1.BinToHex1(BinStr: string): string;
const
  BinArray: array [0 .. 15, 0 .. 1] of string = (('0000', '0'), ('0001', '1'),
    ('0010', '2'), ('0011', '3'), ('0100', '4'), ('0101', '5'), ('0110', '6'),
    ('0111', '7'), ('1000', '8'), ('1001', '9'), ('1010', 'A'), ('1011', 'B'),
    ('1100', 'C'), ('1101', 'D'), ('1110', 'E'), ('1111', 'F'));
var
  Error: Boolean;
  j: Integer;
  BinPart: string;
begin
  Result := '';

  Error := False;
  for j := 1 to Length(BinStr) do
    if not(BinStr[j] in ['0', '1']) then
    begin
      Error := True;
      ShowMessage('This is not binary number');
      Break;
    end;

  if not Error then
  begin
    case Length(BinStr) mod 4 of
      1:
        BinStr := '000' + BinStr;
      2:
        BinStr := '00' + BinStr;
      3:
        BinStr := '0' + BinStr;
    end;

    while Length(BinStr) > 0 do
    begin
      BinPart := Copy(BinStr, Length(BinStr) - 3, 4);
      Delete(BinStr, Length(BinStr) - 3, 4);
      for j := 1 to 16 do
        if BinPart = BinArray[j - 1, 0] then
          Result := BinArray[j - 1, 1] + Result;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Also, may I ask what version of Indy do you use? As far as I remember, my Indy uses `AData: Array of Byte` for storing AData bytes, not TIdBytes...  I remember that one of the Indy dev team members answered to this once I was asking something around AData...

Comment: @JustMarc: Indy does not use `array of byte` for the `AData` parameter anymore. That was a [bug that Embarcadero introduced in XE3](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20120905.EN.aspx), and was fixed in a later release.

Comment: So that is my buggy XE3 then, hah. I knew it was something about Emba, as I remember a topic where you explained Indy team was not responsible for that. Didn't remember it was array that was mistaken..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is unnecessarily complex.  Indy has many functions in its `IdGlobal` unit for working with `TIdBytes` data.  For example, you can simplify your example to the following:

```
procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
  if BytesToString(AData) <> 'Hello' then begin
    ABinding.SendTo(ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, ToBytes(Byte(0)));
  end;
  memo1.Lines.Add(ToHex(AData));
  Memo1.GoToTextEnd;
end;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for!  I have learned a lot. Thanks to you and all the other replies as well!!

Answer (score 2):

To convert AData to a string of hex characters, use the BinToHex function in the Classes unit.

```
var
  MyHexString: string;
  ...
begin
  SetLength(MyHexString, 2 * Length(AData));  // 2 * because one byte is represented by two characters
  BinToHex(AData, @MyHexString[1], Length(AData));
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Indy has its own `ToHex()` overloaded functions, one of which takes a `TIdBytes` as input.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the data as AnsiChars directly to a string by using SetString function like this:

```
var MyString: AnsiString;

SetString(MyString, PAnsiChar(@AData[0]), Length(AData));
```

However if you need HEX values, @Tom gave you the answer you need.

There are several functions to get Hex values already implemented in the Delphi itself, one is BinToHex mentioned in Tom's answer, then there's IntToHex where you can convert Integer or Byte values to Hex string, such as

```
// for int:
MyString:=IntToHex(integer, 2);  

// or for byte:
MyString:=IntToHex(byte, 2);        

// or for array of byte:
var MyArray: array of byte;

for i := 0 to Length(MyArray)-1 do
  MyString:=MyString + ' ' + IntToHex(MyArray[i], 2);    
// this adds all contents of MyArray to the string as Hex values, with space between each of them;
```

Depends what you actually need as result...